# Inject user entity with EJB

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I use JAAS authentication in my application. Think think that I have User Entity class like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    ...
```

and a rest API like this:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/users")
public class Users {

    // INJECT USER OBJECT HERE
    @Inject
    private User user;

    @Path("/me")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @GET
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    ...
```

Is there anyway I create a `@Produces` method to generate User entity object from `@SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()` and EntityManager and Inject it directly into the all rest apis that I want?

Comment: What class is `User`? Does it map to JSON?

Answer (score 2):

When you saved the id of user as principle name following way should work.
 You need a [qualifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html) and a producer method. A good way is to create another class to get the user entity.

```
public class Resource {
  @Inject
  private EntityManager em;

  @Resource
  private SessionContext ctx;

  @Produces
  @Sessionscoped
  @Running // the qualifier
  public User getUser() {
    User user = em.find(User.class, ctx.getCallerPrincipal().getName());
    return user;
  }
}
```

In your `Users` class, you have to annotate the injected user with the qualifier to. Otherwise the User entity of the producer method can not be alloacted to the injection.

```
@Inject
@Running
private User user;
```

Comment: I still have problem. ctx is null, probably because the method is SessiopnScoped not the class. I want to inject my User object (as RequestScoped scope) into Jersey rest API class (So I will have the right User object for every request). I did everything that I can imagine for days, nothing works :(

Comment: this is not an answer to the main question, that is: how to send user info to EJB context (actually you are injecting ctx from HTTP resource which is obviously operable)